# SQL Server Conditional Group By

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Busting my stackoverflow.com cherry!

I have a SQL Server 2008 table that holds ten nchar(1) columns. I was trying to write a stored proc to query the table to get the counts grouped by any combination of the ten columns. For instance, say I have these rows in the table:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10
+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======
|  T   |  P   |  9   |  C   |  )   |  N   |  N   |  S   |  X   |  X   
|  T   |  P   |  9   |  7   |  0   |  *   |  N   |  Q   |  X   |  X   
|  T   |  P   |  I   |  B   |  (   |  H   |  N   |  S   |  X   |  X   
|  T   |  P   |  A   |  A   |  G   |  S   |  N   |  6   |  X   |  X
```

I want to be able to group on columns 1 and 3 and get:

```
COUNT | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10
+=====+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+=============
|   2 |  T   |  -   |  9   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   
|   1 |  T   |  -   |  A   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   
|   1 |  T   |  -   |  I   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -
```

Or I want to be able to group on columns 1, 2 and 8 and get:

```
COUNT | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10
+=====+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+=============
|   2 |  T   |  P   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  S   |  -   |  -   
|   1 |  T   |  P   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  6   |  -   |  -   
|   1 |  T   |  P   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -   |  Q   |  -   |  -
```

I think I can dynamically create the query on the client-side and be done with it. I think that would be the simplest solution right now.  But for future reference is there a simple way to do this on the server-side *without using dynamic SQL*? Well, I have always read that dynamic SQL is *usually* a bad idea.  Would it be the preferred method in this case?

(Try not to flame me too bad if I haven't followed stackoverflow.com etiquette. Please just point it out and I'll try to do better next time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetGroups (
  @Col1 bit,
  @Col2 bit,
  @Col3 bit,
  @Col4 bit,
  @Col5 bit,
  @Col6 bit,
  @Col7 bit,
  @Col8 bit,
  @Col9 bit,
  @Col10 bit
)
AS
SELECT
  COUNT = COUNT(*),
  CASE @col1  WHEN 1 THEN COL1  END COL1,
  CASE @col2  WHEN 1 THEN COL2  END COL2,
  CASE @col3  WHEN 1 THEN COL3  END COL3,
  CASE @col4  WHEN 1 THEN COL4  END COL4,
  CASE @col5  WHEN 1 THEN COL5  END COL5,
  CASE @col6  WHEN 1 THEN COL6  END COL6,
  CASE @col7  WHEN 1 THEN COL7  END COL7,
  CASE @col8  WHEN 1 THEN COL8  END COL8,
  CASE @col9  WHEN 1 THEN COL9  END COL9,
  CASE @col10 WHEN 1 THEN COL10 END COL10
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
  CASE @col1  WHEN 1 THEN COL1  END,
  CASE @col2  WHEN 1 THEN COL2  END,
  CASE @col3  WHEN 1 THEN COL3  END,
  CASE @col4  WHEN 1 THEN COL4  END,
  CASE @col5  WHEN 1 THEN COL5  END,
  CASE @col6  WHEN 1 THEN COL6  END,
  CASE @col7  WHEN 1 THEN COL7  END,
  CASE @col8  WHEN 1 THEN COL8  END,
  CASE @col9  WHEN 1 THEN COL9  END,
  CASE @col10 WHEN 1 THEN COL10 END
```

---

**UPDATE**

By the way, since the resulting query is not constructed dynamically, you can implement it as a table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetGroups (
  @Col1 bit,
  @Col2 bit,
  @Col3 bit,
  @Col4 bit,
  @Col5 bit,
  @Col6 bit,
  @Col7 bit,
  @Col8 bit,
  @Col9 bit,
  @Col10 bit
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
  SELECT
  …
)
```

and call it instead from the SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetGroups (
  @Col1 bit,
  @Col2 bit,
  @Col3 bit,
  @Col4 bit,
  @Col5 bit,
  @Col6 bit,
  @Col7 bit,
  @Col8 bit,
  @Col9 bit,
  @Col10 bit
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM fnGetGroups(@Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4, @Col5,
                 @Col6, @Col7, @Col8, @Col9, @Col10)
```

The thing is, a TVF can be handier to use in various SQL scripts, while an SP could be preferable to call directly from the application.